# Delete strings from file using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I have `csv` file

```
ID,"address","used_at","active_seconds","pageviews"
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"vk.com",2016-01-29 22:10:52,3804,115
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"2gis.ru",2016-01-29 22:48:52,214,24
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"yandex.ru",2016-01-29 22:14:30,4,2
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9,"worldoftanks.ru",2016-01-29 22:10:30,41,2
```

and I need remove strings, that contains some words. There are 117 words.

I try

```
for line in df:
    if 'yandex.ru' in line:
        df = df.replace(line, '')
```

but to 117 words it works too slowly and after it I create `pivot_table` and words, that I try to delete, contains in columns.

```
             aaa                         10ruslake.ru  youtube.ru 1tv.ru  24open.ru
0   0025977ab2998580d4559af34cc66a4e             0        0       34      43
1   00c651e018cbcc8fe7aa57492445c7a2             230      0       0       23
2   0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca             12       0       0       0
3   01249e90ed8160ddae82d2190449b773             25       0       13      25
```

That columns contain only `0`

How Can I do it faster and remove lines so as that words are not be in columns?

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry you're iterating over your df columns and then testing whether a word is present and replacing with empty string? Are your words in a list? if so you can try `pattern = '|'.join(words)' for col in df: df[col] = df.str.replace(pattern, '', case=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df
                                 ID          address              used_at  \
0  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9           vk.com  2016-01-29 22:10:52   
1  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9           vk.com  2016-01-29 22:10:52   
2  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9          2gis.ru  2016-01-29 22:48:52   
3  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9        yandex.ru  2016-01-29 22:14:30   
4  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9  worldoftanks.ru  2016-01-29 22:10:30   

   active_seconds  pageviews  
0            3804        115  
1            3804        115  
2             214         24  
3               4          2  
4              41          2  

words = ['vk.com','yandex.ru']

print ~df.address.isin(words)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: address, dtype: bool

print df[~df.address.isin(words)]
                                 ID          address              used_at  \
2  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9          2gis.ru  2016-01-29 22:48:52   
4  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9  worldoftanks.ru  2016-01-29 22:10:30   

   active_seconds  pageviews  
2             214         24  
4              41          2
```

Then use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print df[~df.address.isin(words)].pivot(index='ID', columns='address', values='pageviews')
address                           2gis.ru  worldoftanks.ru
ID                                                        
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9       24                2
```

Another solution is removed rows, when in some column is `0` (e.g. `pageviews` ):

```
print df

                                 ID          address              used_at  \
0  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9       youtube.ru  2016-01-29 22:10:52   
1            0a1d796327284ebfsffsdf       youtube.ru  2016-01-29 22:10:52   
2  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9           vk.com  2016-01-29 22:10:52   
3  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9          2gis.ru  2016-01-29 22:48:52   
4  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9        yandex.ru  2016-01-29 22:14:30   
5  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9  worldoftanks.ru  2016-01-29 22:10:30   

   active_seconds  pageviews  
0            3804          0  
1            3804          0  
2            3804        115  
3             214         24  
4               4          2  
5              41          2
```

```
print df.pageviews != 0
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: pageviews, dtype: bool

print df[(df.pageviews != 0)]
                                 ID          address              used_at  \
2  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9           vk.com  2016-01-29 22:10:52   
3  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9          2gis.ru  2016-01-29 22:48:52   
4  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9        yandex.ru  2016-01-29 22:14:30   
5  0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9  worldoftanks.ru  2016-01-29 22:10:30   

   active_seconds  pageviews  
2            3804        115  
3             214         24  
4               4          2  
5              41          2  

print df[(df.pageviews != 0)].pivot_table(index='ID', columns='address', values='pageviews')
address                           2gis.ru  vk.com  worldoftanks.ru  yandex.ru
ID                                                                           
0a1d796327284ebb443f71d85cb37db9       24     115                2          2
```

Comment: I asked question from another account http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839602/save-table-to-different-excel-sheets-using-python/36839659?noredirect=1#comment61250977_36839659  . I need to delete columns with some `url`. And I try to delete strings in original `csv` file and after that create a `pivot_table`

Comment: Hmmm, you need delete some rows in data, where column `address` contains some strings? Or substrings? before pivot? If yes, you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: minor point wouldn't this be more readable `df[df.pageviews != 0]`?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I know to work on csv files is to use the package Pandas to create a dataframe from it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(the_path_of_your_file,header = 0)
df.ix[df.ix[:,'address'] == 'yandex.ru','address'] = ''
```

This replaces the cells containing 'yandex.ru' by an cell with an empty string.
Then you can write it back as a csv with:

```
df.to_csv(the_path_of_your_file)
```

If what you want to do is erasing the rows where that url occurs, use:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.address == 'yandex.ru'].index)
```